# Blender Eeve: transparent texture

Tags: texturing, materials, eevee-render-engine, transparency

How could I put put a node with a transparent texture coming from a picture? I don't want any reflexion, just display a normal image.

Answer (score 1):

So to get alpha working on a texture, click in the material on "Use Nodes" and change the color to use an image:

[image]

Also make sure to set the `Settings/Blend mode` of your material to `Alpha Blend`:
[image]

Then, open the Shader Editor to edit the nodes, and *make sure that the alpha is set to Premultiplied* in the settings (press N) of your texture. Then, create a node (`Shift-A`) `Transparent BSDF`, make sure it is white, and mix it with your image, using the alpha as factor (if you want to keep material, you can use the `Principled BSDF` node as input to your color instead):

[image]

This gives you something like that:

[image]

If you get a white border around edges, make sure that you selected `Alpha: Premultiplied`.